# Algorithm to perform a bracket rate calculation

Tags: php, algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures

Let's consider a bracketed tariff which for each service has three (or more) brackets [or classes? I'm not sure of the correct english phrase].

Example, a parking which has rates for different vehicles and in the case of a car less than 4 meters long bills in this way:

- first 2 days are free (or lump sum of 10 dollars), then
- next 3 days: 5 dollars per day
- next 4 days: 8 dollars per day
- next 2 days: 10 dollars per day
- days after: 15 dollars per day

So if I stay 8 days, I'll pay 2*0+3*5+3*8 = 36 dollars.

My initial logic was:

1. remove free days then
2. for each bracket: check if there are still days, if they are more than the current bracket span, sum the maximum amount and continue, otherwise sum only the remaining amount.

My question is: can this logic be improved? (Are there smarter algorithms)

What data structure can hold the tariff information in a way that I can walk when executing the algorithm? I saw the data represented as a table in a database with (car, free days, bracket_span_1, amount_span_1, bracket_span_2, amount_span_2 ...) [but it isn't generic enough], and in the past I tried with a dictionary {car: {free: 2, [span_1: [days: 2, amount: 5],...} but I don't really like this solution, hence the question.

As the tagging of the question implies, I'm using PHP for the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your bracket days and rates in an array as key/value pairs then loop over the number of days the car is parked.

```
$brackets=array(0=>0,2=>5,5=>8,9=>10,11=>15); // At 0 days rate is 0, from day 2 rate is $5 per day etc 
$days = 8;
$total = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $days; ++$i)  {      // Loop over each day
    if (isset($brackets[$i])) {
        $rate = $brackets[$i];         // Set new rate if applicable
    }
    $total = $total + $rate;           // Add daily rate to total
}
echo 'Total is $'.$total;
```

Comment: Nice and simple! I made a test array as you suggest and it's so simple that I wonder if I was overthinking the problem :D Tomorrow I try the complete solution and in case I accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You could encode the brackets just like you describe in the bullet list, with pairs of [number of "next" days, cost for those days]. Then you need at most a number of iterations equal to the number of different brackets. So even if a car is parked for 200 days, the loop will only iterate 5 times:

```
$brackets = [[2, 0], [3, 5] , [4, 8], [2, 10], [PHP_INT_MAX, 15]];

$days = 8;
$total = 0;
foreach ($brackets as list($nextDays, $dayFee)) {
    $total += min($nextDays, $days) * $dayFee;
    $days -= $nextDays;
    if ($days <= 0) break;
}
echo "Total is \$$total\n";
```